# Gradle : Print dependency graph for local filesystem jar dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

For some strange reasons I MUST have to use jars from local file system and it is serving our purpose as well.

In short

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "${lib}/", includes: ['*.jar'])
}
```

OR in detailed we have many `configurations` lib bifurcation as below.

```
dependencies {
 aspectTools files("${lib}/aspectj-${ASPECTJ_VERSION}/aspectjtools-${ASPECTJ_VERSION}.jar")
 aspectJrt files("${lib}/aspectj-${ASPECTJ_VERSION}/aspectjrt-${ASPECTJ_VERSION}.jar")
 infraLibs(
        configurations.aspectJrt +
        configurations.aspectTools +
        fileTree("${lib}/log4j-${LOG4J_API_VERSION}") { include '*.jar' } +
        fileTree(dir: "${lib}",
            includes: [
                "commons-lang-2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar",
                "commons-beanutils-1.9.4/commons-beanutils.jar"
            ]
        )
    )

}
```

I'm trying to print those dependencies as

```
./gradlew myproject:dependencies  --configuration infraLibs
```

But it is not printing those jars, how should I print local jars?

Simple outcome is `No dependencies`

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Project :myproject
------------------------------------------------------------

infraLibs
No dependencies
```

Comment: If that is in your `configurations` block, then isn't that where you _create_ the `infraLibs` configuration? I would expect this `fileTree` stuff should be in `dependencies`. Something like `dependencies { infraLibs fileTree("${lib}/log4j-${LOG4J_API_VERSION}") { include '*.jar' } }`.

Comment: Yes, I've many sections in `Configuration` e.g `infraLibs` that I specified. My question is I want to print this dependencies.. how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured it out by my own using classpath as below

```
task printInfraLibs {
    doLast {
        configurations.infraLibs.each { dep ->
            println "$dep.name"
        }
    }
}
```